# Does Python have any for loop equivalent (not foreach)

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Python's iterators are great and all, but sometimes I really do want a C-style for loop - not a foreach loop. For example, I have a start date and an end date and I want to do something for every day in that range. I can do this with a while loop, of course:

```
    current = start
    while current <= finish:
        do_stuff(current)
        current += timedelta(1)
```

This works, but it's 3 lines instead of 1 (in C or C-based languages) and I often find myself forgetting to write the incrementing line, especially if the loop body is quite complex. Is there a more elegant and less error-prone way of doing this in Python?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The elegant and Pythonic way to do it is to encapsulate the idea of a range of dates in its own generator, then use that generator in your code:

```
import datetime

def daterange(start, end, delta):
    """ Just like `range`, but for dates! """
    current = start
    while current < end:
        yield current
        current += delta

start = datetime.datetime.now()
end = start + datetime.timedelta(days=20)

for d in daterange(start, end, datetime.timedelta(days=1)):
    print d
```

prints:

```
2009-12-22 20:12:41.245000
2009-12-23 20:12:41.245000
2009-12-24 20:12:41.245000
2009-12-25 20:12:41.245000
2009-12-26 20:12:41.245000
2009-12-27 20:12:41.245000
2009-12-28 20:12:41.245000
2009-12-29 20:12:41.245000
2009-12-30 20:12:41.245000
2009-12-31 20:12:41.245000
2010-01-01 20:12:41.245000
2010-01-02 20:12:41.245000
2010-01-03 20:12:41.245000
2010-01-04 20:12:41.245000
2010-01-05 20:12:41.245000
2010-01-06 20:12:41.245000
2010-01-07 20:12:41.245000
2010-01-08 20:12:41.245000
2010-01-09 20:12:41.245000
2010-01-10 20:12:41.245000
```

This is similar to the answer about `range`, except that the built-in `range` won't work with datetimes, so we have to create our own, but at least we can do it just once in an encapsulated way.

Comment: +1 not only because it's the only answer that **actually works** but also bacause it's the right one. Seriously, don't vote up answers that just *look good*

Comment: Aside from a generator, one could take the approach that Python 3.x's built-in `range` does, and use a class that implements `__getitem__` and `__len__` by doing some math. This way, the same instance can be reused, as it's an iterable rather than just an iterator - see also [Why can't I iterate twice over the same iterator? How can I "reset" the iterator or reuse the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336726). In 2009, this would have been supported, but the underlying idiom would (I suppose) have been in some sense less familiar.

Answer (score 2):

Doing it in a compact way it's not easy in Python, as one of the basic concepts behind the language is not being able to make assignments on comparisons.

For something complex, like a date, I think that the answer of Ned is great, but for easier cases, I found very useful the itertools.count() function, which return consecutive numbers.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> begin = 10
>>> end = 15
>>> for i in itertools.count(begin):
...   print 'counting ', i
...   if i > end:
...     break
...
counting  10
counting  11
counting  12
counting  13
counting  14
counting  15
counting  16
```

I found it less error-prone, as it's easy, as you said, to forget the 'current += 1'. To me it seems more natural to make an infinite loop and then check for an end condition.

Comment: WTF? Why not just use `for i in xrange(begin, end):`?

Answer (score 1):

This will work in a pinch:

```
def cfor(start, test_func, cycle_func):
    """A generator function that emulates the most common case of the C for
    loop construct, where a variable is assigned a value at the begining, then
    on each next cycle updated in some way, and exited when a condition
    depending on that variable evaluates to false. This function yields what
    the value would be at each iteration of the for loop.

    Inputs:
        start: the initial yielded value
        test_func: called on the previous yielded value; if false, the
                   the generator raises StopIteration and the loop exits.
        cycle_func: called on the previous yielded value, retuns the next
                    yielded value
    Yields:
        var: the value of the loop variable

    An example:

    for x in cfor(0.0, lambda x: x <= 3.0, lambda x: x + 1.0):
        print x    # Obviously, print(x) for Python 3

    prints out

    0.0
    1.0
    2.0
    3.0

    """
    var = start
    while test_func(var):
        yield var
        var = cycle_func(var)
```

Answer (score -2):

For the sake of iterating only, you should actually use **xrange** over range, since xrange will simply return an iterator, whereas range will create an actual list object containing the whole integer range from first to last-1 (which is obviously less efficient when all you want is a simple for-loop):

```
for i in xrange(current,finish+1, timedelta(1)):
    do_stuff(i)
```

Additionally, there is enumerate, which returns an enumerate object that will yield an incrementing count and the value of a collection, i.e.:

```
l = ["a", "b", "c"]
for ii, value in enumerate(l):
    print ii, value
```

Result:

```
0 a
1 b
2 c
```

Comment: -1 Test answers before you publish. Result is `TypeError: an integer is required`. All args of `xrange()` must be integers.

Comment: `xrange` should have been named `irange` as it returns an iterator while `range` should always return a list; the only constraint on `xrange` should be that `next=start; next=next+step; until next==end`, i.e. that `start` must be `__add__`able to `step` and the result must be `__cmp__`able to `end`