# Enumerate a DateRange

Tags: python, datetime

I have 2 dates and I am trying to build labels of an x-axis of a plot.

As such, I need a way to take 2 **datetime** objects, i.e **2009-10-12 00:00:00** and **2009-10-20 00:00:00** and generate a list like so:

```
["2009-10-12", "2009-10-13", "2009-10-14", ..., "2009-10-19", "2009-10-20"]
```

What libraries should I use to assist? I have a feeling the **datetime** module and the **timedelta** functionality will help quite a bit.

I can include code if it makes sense to, but I have a feeling there's something built in to the python libraries that allow for this to be real easy. I seem to just be missing it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950098/does-python-have-any-for-loop-equivalent-not-foreach

Comment: Exact Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060279/iterating-through-a-range-of-dates-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import datetime

first=datetime.date(2009,10,12)
last=datetime.date(2009,10,20)
adate=first
dates=[]
while adate<=last:
    dates.append(adate)
    adate+=datetime.timedelta(1)
print(dates)
```

Or, for lovers of list comprehension:

```
len=(last-first).days
dates=[first+datetime.timedelta(n) for n in range(len+1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

a, b = date(1010, 10, 12), date(1010, 10, 20)
times = [a + timedelta(x) for x in xrange((b-a).days)]

# If you want to format them:
times = [x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for x in times]
```

Comment: This is with datetime.date objects, but datetime.datetime should work the same.