# Python: calling 'list' on a map object twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I wanted to calculate the sum of squares up to n. Say n is 4. Then this code generates a list a map object in the range 0 to 4:

```
m = map(lambda x: x**2, range(0,4))
```

Ease enough. Now call list on m, and then sum:

```
>>> sum(list(m))
14
```

The unexpected behavior is that if I run the last line again, the sum is 0:

```
>>> sum(list(m))
0
```

I suspect that this is because calling `list(m)` returns an empty list, but I can't find an explanation for this behavior. Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: `map` is an *iterator*, which is consumed by the first `list` call. Why don't you assign `list(m)` and reuse that?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, I see that is an alternative, but I wanted to know why this happens. So you're saying that list() consumes the iterator? Can you tell me more (or where to find out more)?

Comment: Python tutorials/documentation? Google search for *"python iterator"*?

Comment: Would be better to say that the list call consumes the _generator_.

Comment: No, it wouldn't: https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists

Comment: "map(_function, iterable,_ ...) Return an iterator that applies _function_ to every item of _iterable_, yielding the results"   (https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#map) So I believe the 'yielding' is what tripped me up here...

Comment: Also type(m) returns <map object at 0x...>. This seems to conflict with the docs, which state that map() returns an iterator.

Comment: ...a map object *is an iterator*.

Comment: Not being pedantic! But would like to see this in the docs (map object == iterator). In the meantime this is also helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python?rq=1

Comment: 1. The docs tell you repeatedly that the result is an iterator, the fact that it's specifically a map object is largely irrelevant (not least because, told that you get an iterator and finding you get a map object, the fact that a map object is an iterator should have been your first conclusion). 2. Don't tell me, I don't maintain Python.

Comment: In case anyone (beside jonrsharpe) has the same question that I did, a good stackexchange question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`map` returns a stateful iterator in Python 3. Stateful iterators may be only consumed once, after that it's exhausted and yields no values.

In your code snippet you **consume** iterator multiple times. `list(m)` each time tries to recreate list, and for second and next runs created list will always be empty (since source iterator was consumed in first `list(m)` operation).

Simply convert iterator to list once, and operate on said list afterwards.

```
m = map(lambda x: x**2, range(0,4))
l = list(m)
assert sum(l) == 14
assert sum(l) == 14
```

Comment: If you'd like to avoid this behavior with generators, you could instead skip the map and go straight to a list using a list comprehension. `m = [x**2 for x in range(4)]`

Comment: I have altered your answer, because `map()` returns iterators, not generators - `isinstance(map(lambda x: x**2, range(0,4)), types.GeneratorType) == False`. Returned object lacks `send()`, `throw()`, which is logical due to `map()` semantics, as it's not possible to communicate back to the object being mapped through.