# Difference in using list() and map() together and using them separately in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I encountered a weird phenomena while playing around with python. 
The following two different codes give different outputs whereas, in my opinion, they (the codes) should be equivalent.

**Snippet 1:**

```
store1 = [10.00, 11.00, 12.34, 2.34]
store2 = [9.00, 11.10, 12.34, 2.01]
cheapest = list(map(min, store1, store2))
print(list(cheapest))
list(cheapest)
```

**Snippet 2:**

```
store1 = [10.00, 11.00, 12.34, 2.34]
store2 = [9.00, 11.10, 12.34, 2.01]
cheapest = (map(min, store1, store2))
print(list(cheapest))
list(cheapest)  #shows empty list
```

Looking at the outputs from these two snippets (the only difference in declaration of `cheapest` from line 3), I conclude that using `list(x)`, where `x` is a map, at any other point other than declaration of the variable, actually deletes/clears the contents of the map.

I can't figure out why this is happening (or if my inference is even correct), any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Map returns an iterator in Python 3. On the second “read” it has already been used up, and returns 0 elements making for an empty list - see https://portingguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/iterators.html, which explains the behavior (and difference from Python 2)

Comment: @user2864740 what do you mean by 'used up'? I have a stronger background in c++, and in that language an iterator points to the same location and the data being pointed to remains till overwritten. So an equivalent code in c++ will have same output for both the snippets.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36486950/2864740

Comment: in C++ terms, using the result of map a second time is akin to using an iterator already at my_map.end(). Python iterators effectively maintain their own position.

Comment: @user2864740 ah that makes more sense. So the iterator remains at map.end() or can we move it back to the front? P.S. reading up on the resources you tagged

Comment: No, so I guess that wasn’t the best example :) Some options include 1) materializing in list; 2) using a wrapping object like itertools “tee”; or 3) using a function/closure that re-evaluates to a new iterator from the same data.

Comment: You're giving me ways to work around this?
Thats alright, there will be scores of ways to work around it, I'm just trying to understand how python works and what all I _can_ do in the language
Thanks for all your help and the sources you tagged. I'm getting my doubts cleared :)