# How does list() affect the argument being passed into it in Python?

Tags: python, list

This is the code with `list` function commented out:

```
from collections import Counter

a = input().split() 
b = map(int, a) 
##c = list(b) 
d = Counter(b)

print(d)
```

> **Input: 1 2 3**
>   **Output: Counter({1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1})**

However, when i remove the hashtags, assign `c` to `list(b)` and rerun the code this occurs:

```
Input: 1 2 3

Output: Counter()
```

My question is, Why is it that the counter output values differ if b is not being assigned any new type? From what i know, b would not be affected by this operation? Please forgive me if its a dumb question, I am still quite new to coding. Thanks!

Comment: `map()` returns an iterator. You can only loop through it once. When you use `list(b)` it exhausts the iterator. See also: [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36486950/python-calling-list-on-a-map-object-twice)

Answer (score 0):

Python map() function is used to apply a function on all the elements of specified iterable and return map object. Python map object is an iterator, so we can iterate over its elements.

```
b = map(int, a)
```

This only maps 'int' function to each element in a. (Not executes).

when you call the iterator it executes and returns the value and clears.

for example

```
a = list(range(5))
for i in a:
 print(i)
 break
```

Outputs

```
0

for i in a:
 print(i)
 break
```

Outputs

```
1 #now it returns next element
```

And goes on. This is a type of on-demand execution