# map in Python 3 vs Python 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, iterator, python-2.x

I'm a Python newbie reading an old Python book. It's based on Python 2, so sometimes I got little confused about detail.

There is a code

```
L=map(lambda x:2**x, range(7))
```

so it doesn't return the list in python 3, and I googled it and found that `list(L`) works.
But the problem is, first `list(L)` works fine,
but when I use it again,

```
list(L)

list(L)
```

second one returns `[ ]`

Can somebody explain me what's happening?

Comment: If you want to use `L` more than once, make `L` a list: `L=list(map(lambda x:2**x, range(7)))`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`map` returns an iterator. As such, its output may only be used once. If you wish to store your results in a list, in the same way as Python 2.x, simply call `list` when you use `map`:

```
L = list(map(lambda x:2**x, range(7)))
```

The list `L` will now contain your results however many times you call it.

The problem you are facing is that once `map` has iterated once, it will yield nothing for each subsequent call. Hence you see an empty list for the second call.

For a more detailed explanation and advice on workarounds if you cannot exhaust your iterator but wish to use it twice, see [Why can't I iterate twice over the same data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336726/why-cant-i-iterate-twice-over-the-same-data).

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.x returns a generator object:

```
$ python3 -c "print(map(lambda x: 2**x, range(7)))" 
<map object at 0x104203208>
```

You can extract those values using `list()`, but generators can be depleted. Hence subsequent use of `list()` will result in an empty `[]` since there are no more values to access with `next()` calls. I'd recommend experimenting with generators a little, or read a bit here https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators. Hope this helps