# Doubley unpacking an iterable in Python 3 removes the iterable?

Tags: python

```
lst = iter([1, 2, 3])
print([*lst])  # >>> [1, 2, 3]
print([*lst])  # >>> []
```

Is this expected behaviour for unpacking? I would've assumed the original data wouldn't be modified on unpacking and a copy is simply made?

EDIT:

If so, what is the reasoning behind it?

Comment: Why would you assume a copy is made? Would that be desirable behavior?

Comment: Here is an answer explaing it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25336738/8472976 It is not a duplicate, because the question are quite different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [glossary entry for iterators](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) (my emphasis):

> A container object (such as a list) produces a fresh new iterator each time you pass it to the iter() function or use it in a for loop. *Attempting this with an iterator will just return the same exhausted iterator object used in the previous iteration pass, **making it appear like an empty container.***

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is expected behavior for unpacking an *iterator*:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> iter(lst)
<list_iterator at 0x7fffe8b84ef0>
```

The iterator can only be iterated once and then it is exhausted.

```
>>> i = iter(lst)
>>> next(i)
1
>>> next(i)
2
>>> next(i)
3
>>> next(i)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-a883b34d6d8a> in <module>()
----> 1 next(i)

StopIteration:
```

The iterator protocol specifies that an exhausted iterator must continue raising `StopIteration` exceptions on subsequent calls of its `__next__` method.  Therefore, iterating it once again is valid (not an error), but the iterator should yield no new items:

```
>>> list(i)
[]
```

Nothing prevents you to define an iterator which disobeys this rule, but [such iterators are deemed "broken"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types).

The list *iterable* could be unpacked multiple times, however.

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> print(*lst)
1 2 3
>>> print(*lst)
1 2 3
```

And you could create as many independent iterators, from the same source list, as you want:

```
>>> i1 = iter(lst)
>>> i2 = iter(lst)
>>> next(i2)
1
>>> next(i2)
2
>>> next(i1)  # note: it's another 1
1
```

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the terminology of "iterator" and "iterable".

An iterator (typically) can't be iterated over again. An *iterable* on the other hand (like a list) can:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
print([*lst])  # >>> [1, 2, 3]
print([*lst])  # >>> [1, 2, 3]
```