# A nested loop with itertools.product runs only 1 time

Tags: python, python-itertools

I got a little bit of a problem here. I'm trying to make a nested loop, but the second loop only runs one time.

Here is the code:

```py
def solver(numbers, gleichung_list = [], temp = []):
    perm = itertools.permutations(numbers)
    permlist = [list(y) for y in perm]
    oper = itertools.product(['+', '-', '*', '/'], repeat=len(numbers)-1)
    for gleichung in permlist:
        print(gleichung)
        for ops in oper:
            print(ops)
            temp = [None] * (len(numbers)*2-1)
            temp[::2] = list(gleichung)
            temp[1::2] = list(ops)
            print(temp)
            print(ops)

    numbers = [1, 2]
    solver(numbers)
```

But when i run it, this is what i got:

```
[1, 2]
('+',)
[1, '+', 2]
('+',)
('-',)
[1, '-', 2]
('-',)
('*',)
[1, '*', 2]
('*',)
('/',)
[1, '/', 2]
('/',)
[2, 1]
```

Why don't the second loop run?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I iterate twice over the same data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336726/why-cant-i-iterate-twice-over-the-same-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) function returns an iterator and not a list, so your nested loop run once on this iterator and then there is no more items.
Add `oper = list(oper)` before your first loop to correct this problem.

Answer (score 0):

`oper` has come to an end in the first run of the loop and there is nothing left for iterating in the second run. If you just redefine `oper` in the loop it will be alright.

```
def solver(numbers, gleichung_list = [], temp = []):
    perm = itertools.permutations(numbers)
    permlist = [list(y) for y in perm]
    for gleichung in permlist:
        oper = itertools.product(['+', '-', '*', '/'], repeat=len(numbers)-1)
        print(gleichung)
        for ops in oper:
            print(ops)
            temp = [None] * (len(numbers)*2-1)
            temp[::2] = list(gleichung)
            temp[1::2] = list(ops)
            print(temp)
            print(ops)
```