# Python making multiple zip objects will overwrite the first one

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, debugging, range

I was working on a project when I came into this really weird bug, and I have managed to cut it down to this:

```
xr = zip(range(0, 5), range(0, 5))
yr = zip(range(3, 4), range(0, 1))

print(list(xr), list(yr))
print(list(xr))
```

The expected output would be this:

```
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)] [(3, 0)]
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)]
```

Because I don't change xr or yr after I set them. I am just printing them as a list to the shell. But, when I actually run it, I get this output:

```
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)] [(3, 0)]
[]
```

I have absolutely no clue why. I have been using python for about a week, and maybe this is supposed to happen, but I would appreciate it if someone told me what's going on here. Thanks!

My python version is Python 3.8.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're exhausting the iterator.

Use this:

```py
xr = list(zip(range(0, 5), range(0, 5)))
yr = list(zip(range(3, 4), range(0, 1)))

print(xr, yr)
print(xr)
```

Comment: What is meant by "exhausting the generator"? Is there any reference you can point to?

Comment: The [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) is exhausted after traversal. Your usage requires more than once usage of the result. So, turn it into a list.

Comment: This solution works perfectly! I didn't know about how iterators could only be used once, so thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The zip function creates an iterator object, which can only be consumed once. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336726/why-cant-i-iterate-twice-over-the-same-data#:~:text=3%20Answers&text=If%20we%20are%20traversing%20some,iterator%20has%20already%20been%20consumed.&text=Once%20an%20iterator%20is%20exhausted%2C%20it%20will%20not%20yield%20any%20more.) explains why you cannot iterate over data twice.

This [document](https://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html) explains the iterator class.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!