# python itertools combinations disappear

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

When I do:

```
from itertools import combinations
a = combinations ('pdejffd', 2)
print(list(a))
print(list(a))
```

the second print outputs `[]`.

Can someone explain me why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I iterate twice over the same data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336726/why-cant-i-iterate-twice-over-the-same-data) You should do `a = list(combinations('pdejffd', 2))` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) returns a generator.

You've already used it up in the first `list(a)` call.

Comment: Is it possible to save it instead of burning it?

Comment: @BernardoCortez Yep, that's exactly what you did with `list(a)`. But you threw away the result.