# Enumerate object is empty after converting to a list

Tags: python, enumerate

On converting `enumerate` object becomes empty:

```
myTuple = (1, 2, 3)

myEnum = enumerate(myTuple)

print(myEnum)
print(list(myEnum))

print(myEnum)
print(list(myEnum))
```

Comment: `enumerate` returns an object that you can iterate once. That uses it up. It does not "become null".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I iterate twice over the same data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336726/why-cant-i-iterate-twice-over-the-same-data)

Comment: In Python speak, an instance of `enumerate` is an *iterator*. By contrast, a tuple is not an iterator itself, but is an example of an *iterable*; you can call `iter(myTuple)` to get a new iterator over the tuple, which like all iterators can only be iterated over once. Most things that expect an iterator (like `list`) will try to call `iter` on its argument to get an iterator, so that you don't often need to think about the difference between the two.

Answer (score 2):

[`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) returns an object that you can iterate once. That uses it up.

If you want to enumerate a sequence multiple times, you can call `enumerate` multiple times:

```
for i,x in enumerate(my_items):
    print(i,x)
for i,x in enumerate(my_items):
    print(i,x)
```

or you convert the enumerate object to a list, and then iterate that multiple times:

```
enumerated_items = list(enumerate(my_items))
for i,x in enumerated_items:
    print(i,x)
for i,x in enumerated_items:
    print(i,x)
```

What you **can't** do is iterate the enumerate object itself multiple times:

```
e = enumerate(my_items):
for i,x in e:
    print(i,x)
for i,x in e:
    print(i,x) # won't happen
```

because the enumerate object is used up by the first iteration.

In this particular question, passing an enumerate object to `list` is equivalent to iterating through it and adding each item to a list, so that also uses up the enumerate object.