# python console giving wrong output

Tags: python

Why is the output not as I had expected?

This is my code:

```py
a = "NITISH"
a = enumerate(a)
print(list(a))
print(a)
a = list(a)
print(a)
```

The output:

```
[(0, 'N'), (1, 'I'), (2, 'T'), (3, 'I'), (4, 'S'), (5, 'H')]
<enumerate object at 0x0000028262DE7150>
[]
```

the list should not be empty, the following is the output I am expecting:

```
[(0, 'N'), (1, 'I'), (2, 'T'), (3, 'I'), (4, 'S'), (5, 'H')]
```

Comment: `enumerate` returns a generator-like object which is empty after `print(list(a))`.

Answer (score 4):

By:

```
a = enumerate(a)
```

You are converting a into an iterator.

When you do:

```
print(list(a))
```

It uses up the iterator, as iterators can only be used once.

So when you printed out:

```
print(a)
```

And got the response:

```
<enumerate object at 0x0000028262DE7150>
```

That enumerate object is technically still an object, but also a used up iterator that is at the number: `StopIteration`.

So by doing `a = list(a)` on a already used iterator results in an empty list.

Please see:
[Enumerate object is empty after converting to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64698188/enumerate-object-is-empty-after-converting-to-a-list)

And:
[Why can't I iterate twice over the same iterator? How can I "reset" the iterator or reuse the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336726/why-cant-i-iterate-twice-over-the-same-iterator-how-can-i-reset-the-iterator)

Which has much better explanations.

Comment: To be precise `a = enumerate(a)` doesn't "convert" `a`. It rebinds `a` to the result of `enumerate(a)`.

Answer (score 2):

The enumerate function returns a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). These can only be used once. In your code this happens when you call a with list. After that it is "used up".

If you want to further learn about generators in python I can recommend this [video by mCoding](https://youtu.be/tmeKsb2Fras).

Answer (score 1):

`enumerate()` returns a generator, which is similar to a bottle of wine: it will be empty after you've drunk everything from it. That's what calling `list()` does, drinks the full content of the generator. No surprise it will be empty the second time.