# Why aren't two `zip` objects equal if the underlying data is equal?

Tags: python, python-zip

Suppose we create two `zip`s from lists and tuples, and compare them, like so:

```
>>> x1=[1,2,3]
>>> y1=[4,5,6]
>>> x2=(1,2,3)
>>> y2=(4,5,6)
>>> w1=zip(x1,y1)
>>> w2=zip(x2,y2)
>>> w1 == w2
False
```

But using `list` on each `zip` shows the same result:

```
>>> list(w1)
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
>>> list(w2)
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Why don't they compare equal, if the contents are equal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two `zip` objects don't compare equal because the `zip` class doesn't define any logic for comparison, so it uses the default `object` logic that only cares about object identity. In this case, an object can only ever compare equal to **itself**; the object contents don't matter.

So, the `zip` objects will not compare equal **even if they are constructed the same way, from the same immutable data**:

```
>>> x = (1, 2, 3)
>>> y = (4, 5, 6)
>>> zip(x, y) == zip(x, y) # separate objects, therefore not equal
False
```

That said: `zip` objects **don't** "contain" the values in the iteration, which is why they [can't be reused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336726). The only robust way to verify that they'll give the same results when iterated, is to do that iteration.

Internally, the `zip` object just has some iterators over other data. One might think, why not compare the iterators, to see if they "point at" the same position in the same underlying data? But that cannot work, either: there are arbitrarily many ways to implement the iterator, plus the iterator doesn't in general know anything about what it's iterating over. Many iterators won't "know where" they are in the underlying data. Many iterators **aren't** at a position in underlying data, but instead they calculate values on the fly.

Comment: Even simpler case: `zip() == zip()` is also `False`.