# Export itertools permutation to csv

Tags: python

I tried converting an itertools permutation to a pandas dataframe object but when I export the dataframe i do not get the array generated by permutation

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

x = range(69,89)

array = itertools.permutations(x, 4)

for eachpermutation in array:
    print(eachpermutation)

df = pd.DataFrame(eachpermutation) 

df.to_csv("")
```

the eachpermutation is fine and printing what I expect but the df produces the following:

```
    0
0  80
1  79
2  78
3  77
```

Comment: You're just putting the very last permutation into the dataframe…!?

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(itertools.permutations(x, 4))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two problems:

1. You passed `each_permutation` to the `DataFrame` constructor, which means you only passed it the *last* permutation generated as the sole source of data. This is almost certainly not what you wanted; it seems fairly clear the `DataFrame` was intended to be *all* the permutations. To fix this part, change `df = pd.DataFrame(each_permutation)` to `df = pd.DataFrame(array)`.
2. Once that's fixed, you'll have another problem: `permutations` makes an *iterator*, not a new `list` or the like. When you iterated over it with your `for` loop, you consumed all the values in it; [trying to iterate it again produces *nothing*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25336726/364696). If you get rid of that loop, the `permutations` object will be fresh, and the `DataFrame` will receive the values you expect, rather than nothing.

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame(array) worked! thank you so much!