# Django: My context variable cannot be used for duplicate for loops

Tags: django, django-templates, nested-for-loop

In views.py I have the variable

```
mylist = zip(set1,set2,set3)
```

In templates I do

```
{% for val1, val2, val3 in mylist%}
{% endfor %}
```

It works fine. However, if I duplicate the condition it fails. Is it normal? Let's say I have the following:

```
# this is my page
some text
{% for val1, val2, val3 in mylist %}
  {{forloop.counter}}
{% endfor %}
more text
{% for val1, val2, val3 in mylist %}
  {{forloop.counter}}
{% endfor %}
more text
# final text of page
```

The first loop will work, and the second one will be empty. It seems as though I can only use once `mylist`. I didn't experience this issue with simple lists. One solution is to create 2 identical context variables to have 2 for loops but that seems odd...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Please note that…

The first line of code of your question is odd, I would replace it with:

```python
myzip = zip(mylistA,mylistB,mytuple)
```

Indeed, a [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) is iterable, but it doesn’t have any order. So using [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) in this case results in unexpected behaviour.

---

## The answer

`zip()` returns an iterator. [It can only be consumed once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336726/why-cant-i-iterate-twice-over-the-same-iterator-how-can-i-reset-the-iterator).

Try this as well in python:

```python
myzip = zip([1,2,3], ("a","b","c"))

for i,j in myzip:
    print(i, j)

for i,j in myzip:
    print(i, j)
```

You’ll get the same behaviour. It will returns the following **once**:

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

A work-around is to call the `list()` function before any `for` loop:

```python
mylist = list(myzip)
```